# Solving system of differential equations by elimination

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to replace the bracket terms in equation2 with eliminated terms of equation1, by the elimination process, but wasn't successful. I am interested in the dependent variable V only. Is there another way to eliminate the U variable from the final equation?

\begin{align}2U+X \frac{dU}{dx} &= 2\frac{dV}{dx}+X \frac{d^2V}{dx^2}+a^2Vx \tag{1} \\
bX^3 \frac{d}{dx}\bigg(4U + X \frac{dU}{dx}\bigg)&=0 \tag{2} \end{align}

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You'll receive a more help if you include the context of your question, as well as show more engagement in finding the solution. Also, please use MathJax to edit your question. See here for a tutorial: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Is $x$ the same as $X$? And why not reduce the second equation to $4U+xU'=4C$, leading to $x^4U(x)=Cx^4+D$ which can be inserted into the first equation $(x^2U)'=(xV')''+a^2x(xV)$.